# ¿como cambio el formato de fechas en PHP?

Tags: php

```
$fec=$_POST['fecha'];

list($ms,$di,$an)=explode('-',$fec);


$mn=date('m', strtotime($ms));

echo $fecha=$an.'-'.$mn.'-'.$di;
```

mi post fecha viene asi `Feb-31-2019`

y enves de que me ponga en mi variable `$fecha` 2019-02-31 me manda un 2019-03-31 a que se debe??

Comment: Se debe a que febrero nunca tiene 31 días... ¿Te diste cuenta de la fecha que estás recibiendo: `Feb-31-2019`?  ¿Cómo es que permites que se postee una fecha errónea? Deberías controlarlo en el cliente.

Comment: @A.Cedano no pero aun que le ponga Feb-15-2019 no toma en cuenta febrero se brinca de mes

Comment: Pero ¿quien se brinca de mes? Eso no es problema de PHP, el problema está en el cliente, la forma en que son llenados los datos que recibes en el POST. Lo mejor para las fechas es validar o usar un `datepicker` o algo así. En el cliente debes controlar que la fecha no llegue errónea al servidor, porque luego ¡qué sabe el servidor lo que hizo el cliente! ¿se va a poner a adivinar qué fecha era?

Comment: @A.Cedano asi lo manda el POST por que lo que estoy usando es un fullCalendar cuando el cliente quiere mover del fullCalendar al siguiente mes (en este caso de 31 de enero a 5 de febrero) se brinca, le puse un echo y si manda bien todo si manda el mes que es pero a la hora de convertir es el problema

Comment: Te entiendo, pero eso no es problema del servidor (PHP), sino del cliente. Al servidor tienes que mandar los datos correctos sí o sí. Si fullCalendar no está funcionando bien entonces debes corregir el problema con fullCalendar. En PHP yo te puedo indicar cómo crear una fecha correcta con el valor `Feb-15-2019` pero no con el valor `Feb-31-2019` porque no existe un 31 de febrero.

Comment: @A.Cedano pero si en el fullCalendar paso del 31 de enero al 1 de febrero ahi es el problema se brinca de mes, estoy haciendo pruebas con lo que postie en el phptester y asi me manda brincando el mes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con un dato correcto, si la fecha viene en el formato `Feb-15-2019` puedes valerte de **[`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)** para crear un objeto `DateTime` válido a partir de ese formato de fecha.

Luego, puedes usar `format` para presentar la información de tu objeto en el formato deseado o crear variables a través de él.

Por ejemplo:

```
$postFecha='Feb-15-2019'; //Suponiendo que esto es lo que trae el $_POST['fecha'];
$mFecha=DateTime::createFromFormat('M-j-Y',$postFecha);
echo $mFecha->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Salida:**

```
2019-02-15
```

Estamos ante la potencia de los objetos. Significa que `$mFecha` es un objeto y puedes usarlo para representar esa fecha de mil maneras.

Varios ejemplos:

```
echo $mFecha->format('d-m-Y').PHP_EOL;
echo $mFecha->format('d-F-Y').PHP_EOL;
echo $mFecha->format('l, d F Y').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
15-02-2019
15-February-2019
Friday, 15 February 2019
```

Comment: Gracias, e visto que también me sirvió esto, date('m', strtotime(date('Y-').$ms.'-01')); y si por que no mandaba el formato completo

Comment: Ok @JuanJose, pero ten en cuenta que `date` no te crea un objeto `DateTime`, y pierdes por tanto todas las ventajas que esto te podría reportar. Si sólo lo  requieres para mostrarlo bien, pero si hay que hacer cálculos, representar la fecha de maneras distintas, trabajar con la zona horaria, etc es mejor crear un objeto.

Comment: Gracias lo tendré en cuenta, tendre en cuenta