# Cambiar Formato Fechas PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Espero que alguien pueda orientarme para resolver problema con la fecha. Actualmente tengo una lista y me muestra las fechas con el formato Y/m/d, pero necesito que el dia sea primero, quedando de esta forma 01-01-2022 pero no he logrado resolverlo.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
function join_pasantia_table(){
 global $db;
 $sql  =" SELECT p.id,p.fecha_solicitud,p.nombre_docente,p.rut,p.email,p.telefono,p.titulo,p.fecha_inicio,p.fecha_termino,p.registro_sis";
$sql  .=" AS establecimiento,e.nombre AS nombre_establecimiento,c.nombre AS nombre_carrera";
$sql  .=" FROM pasantia p";
$sql  .=" INNER JOIN carr c ON c.id = p.carrera";
$sql  .=" INNER JOIN establecimiento e ON e.id = p.campo_formador";
$sql  .=" ORDER BY p.fecha_solicitud ASC";
return find_by_sql($sql);
```

}

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%;"> Carrera</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;"> Establecimiento </th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 7%;"> Fecha Inicio </th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 8%;"> Fecha Término </th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 100px;"> Acciones </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php foreach ($pasantias as $pasantia):?>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($pasantia['nombre_carrera']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($pasantia['nombre_establecimiento']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo date($pasantia['fecha_inicio']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo date($pasantia['fecha_termino']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="edit_product.php?id=<?php echo (int)$pasantia['id'];?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"  title="Editar" data-toggle="tooltip">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </a>
                 <a href="delete_product.php?id=<?php echo (int)$pasantia['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  title="Eliminar" data-toggle="tooltip">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Convierte primero a una marca de tiempo: `echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($pasantia['fecha_inicio']))`.

Comment: Me funciono, muchas gracias...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo la siguiente lectura: [¿como cambio el formato de fechas en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/234370/como-cambio-el-formato-de-fechas-en-php?rq=1)

1. Tienes que obtener la fecha aparte y guardarla en PHP como una variable tal que así:

```php
$fecha = // guarda la fecha aquí 

//supongamos:
$fecha = '01-01-2022';
```

2. Usa el [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) para crear el formato de fecha que deseas:

```
$fecha_modificada=DateTime::createFromFormat('M-j-Y',$fecha);
echo $fecha_modificada->format('d-m-Y').PHP_EOL;

// output:
// 01-01-2022
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar darle el formato directamente en la base;

```
function join_pasantia_table(){
 global $db;
 $sql  =" SELECT p.id,p.fecha_solicitud,p.nombre_docente,p.rut,p.email,p.telefono,p.titulo,DATE_FORMAT(p.fecha_inicio,'%d-%m-%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(p.fecha_termino,'%d-%m-%Y'),p.registro_sis";
$sql  .=" AS establecimiento,e.nombre AS nombre_establecimiento,c.nombre AS nombre_carrera";
$sql  .=" FROM pasantia p";
$sql  .=" INNER JOIN carr c ON c.id = p.carrera";
$sql  .=" INNER JOIN establecimiento e ON e.id = p.campo_formador";
$sql  .=" ORDER BY p.fecha_solicitud ASC";
return find_by_sql($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma, usando `substr`

```
> $f = "YYYY/mm/dd";
> echo substr($f, 8, 2) . '-' . substr($f, 5, 2) . '-' . substr($f, 0, 4);
dd-mm-YYYY
```

Puedes hacer eso una función para usarlo múltiples veces.